# Does C° also indicate a major seventh chord?

Tags: guitar, chords, jazz

I had always thought that this notation indicated a major seventh chord: [C°]. At least it seemed to make sense that way in some of the chord sheets I have used in the past.

I am now finding that it more commonly seems to represent a diminished chord, as in [Ab°(b13)] or [A flat dim flat 13]. My first question is has anyone here ever seen [°] used to represent a major seventh, or am I labouring under an illusion ;-)

Comment: Hi Welcome to Music.SE. Here we prefer one question per post. This is easier answerable. There's no problem to post a several questions seperately. I edited out your second question and leave it to you to post the second question again as a seperate question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and for adjusting my question appropriately to correspond. I will remember this in future.

Comment: I've never seen ° used to indicate a major seventh. I would note one minor qualification to the answers that state it can only indicate a diminished chord, namely that it can be used in (German-style) Riemannian theory to indicate that a chordal function is minor, e.g., °T is a minor tonic, °D is a minor dominant, °S is a minor subdominant, etc.  It's unlikely that anyone would confuse these with the kind of jazz chord symbols discussed here, but the symbol does occasionally mean something else when referring to a chord.

Answer (score 14):

Never. C° is always C diminished. C major seventh can be signed with a triangle after the C. Bear in mind that half-diminished is signified by a circle with a diagonal line through it.

Cmaj7 is C E G B.

C°7 is C E♭ G♭ B♭♭.

C half dim. is C E♭ G♭ B♭. Note: they all contain C E G B *something*.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - thanks for the degree sign - how did you do it? What about the half-dim though..?

Comment: @Tim: There are various ways to type °, on macOS it is option-shift-8, on Windows it’s alt-0176, on iOS you can hold down the 0 key until the menu appears.

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Or, search Google for "degree sign" and Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V.

Comment: On windows you can also use windows+; to bring up a symbols menu.

Answer (score 6):

I have never ever seen "o" denoting a major 7 chord. A triangle can be used for maj7  in some books (e.g. the Aebersold play alongs), and 'o' is always diminished.

You may also encounter a slashed cirle (ø) for half diminished (min7 b5) chords.

Answer (score 5):

If you're playing from sheet music that's been handwritten, or perhaps photocopied multiple times, it's not uncommon for the small △ symbol, which denotes Maj7 to end up looking like small circle °, which, as you say, denotes Diminished.

Or if the copyist isn't particularly careful, the circle and triangle can end up looking similar.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful suggestion that successive photocopying can degrade the content to the point where errors can creep in. That said, although I have seen some photocopied chord charts, those were not the ones that prompted my question.

Answer (score 5):

`o` a *degree* sign for diminished triad or `o7` for diminished seventh chords.

`ø7` for half-diminished seventh chords.

`Δ7` a delta or triangle for major seventh chords.

Other signs are used capital `M` for major or lower case `m` for minor, etc.

You may have been mistaking the delta for a diminished sign.

Answer (score 2):

> I had always thought that this notation indicated a major seventh chord: [C°]. **At least it seemed to make sense that way in some of the chord sheets I have used in the past.**

This must have been an error. As Cmaj7 is a static chord (or eventuell would lead to F) it couldn't be substituted by C°, while latter might have a dominant function to Db, (or E, G and Bb) and certainly can't be replaced by Cmaj7.

**Edit:**
As the other  answers confirm C°7 was never  meaning **C major 7**.`

I've edited the last words *... was never a major 7* as someone could understand A-major 7 ( **a** was meant as article not as chord).

Comment: Can't see why Cmaj7 would lead to F. C7, yes.

Comment: If you have a tonic chord and there is a passing 7th (Do -Ti) La (3rd of F): e.g. Something (Beatles). oh, this is a bad example ... because Cmaj7 is followed by C7. But there are many others. How about "the long and winding road"? Well, "Imagine" will be clear ...

Comment: Yes, there must have been an error, but it seems to be only the one I made. thanks to all responders for setting me straight on this.

Comment: In jazz, it's common to use a i° to delay the resolution to a I Maj chord. For example, instead of | Dmin | G7 | CMaj |, one could play | Dmin | G7 | C°7 CMaj7 |. This is a common trick among jazz pianists. If we play the C whole-half diminished scale over C°7, then we have access to a BMaj triad, which resolves up a half step to C when we reach the delayed CMaj7 chord.

Answer (score 0):

While answers are correct that C° means C diminished and CΔ means CMaj7, there is more to the story here. In jazz, C° is a very common delayed resolution to CMaj7. For example, in a simple ii-V-I:

```
| Dmin   | G7   | CMaj7     | CMaj7 |
```

it's very common to hear pianists harmonize this with:

```
| Dmin   | G7   | C°7 CMaj7 | CMaj7 |
```

In this context, the scale typically used over C°7 is C whole-half (enharmonically, `C D E♭ F G♭ A♭ A♮ B`). This diminished scale contains the BMaj triad, which resolves up a half step to a CMaj triad when we reach the CMaj7 chord. However, while the C°7 can be voiced with a BMaj triad, this isn't necessarily and isn't always done in jazz. We can simply voice the C°7 chord in its typical fashion.

This isn't all that different from a [common-tone diminished 7th chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminished_seventh_chord#Common-tone_diminished_seventh_chord), which resolves ii<sup>o7</sup> to IMaj (for example, D♯<sup>o7</sup> to CMaj). After all, D♯<sup>o7</sup> has the same notes as C<sup>o7</sup>. But in a jazz context, the bass is often still playing the I, establishing the progress as i<sup>o7</sup> - IMaj7.

Lead sheets may show this i<sup>o7</sup> chord written into the bar, or they may show it above the bar in parentheses to indicate that it's a possible chord substitution. Or, it may not be shown at all, in which case the musician(s) are choosing to add this substitution into the music on the fly.

Comment: I'm not editing, but last para - did you mean **I**o7?

Comment: @Tim, just to clarify, you're asking if the diminished chord should be uppercase instead of lowercase?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure - it's on a I root, in that key, but because it's diminished, maybe it should be marked i. Not sure!

Comment: @Tim, my understanding is that diminished chords are always written with a lowercase numeral. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numeral_analysis#Common_practice_numerals) does show a io.